# How can I filter all questions for a certain time and tag?

Tags: support

I would like to only see the questions for a **certain tag** (Java) in a **given time** (Week) **sorted** by a criterion (most voted).

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20created%3a7d..%20is%3aq)

`[java] created:7d.. is:q`

see also [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)